# Library/Package for web based audio/music processing

Tags: php, javascript, audio, web, audio-player

Online Music albums and music player are very common for many file formats. However, processing music files and applying different effects (say to build karaoke) using a web interface would require a library/package. Are there any good package/library built for music processing (on similar lines as IMAGEMAGIC for images ) on web? I am looking for open source (PHP, JS or similar) code that can be integrated in web development platform. Is there any music player that have such built in facilities to supports such features?

Answer (score 0):

Try http://dashersw.github.com/pedalboard.js/ ... it does certain guitar effects - not exactly sure what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can try Web Audio API:

http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/

or these libraries:

Audiolib.js
http://docs.audiolibjs.org/

Audiolet.js
https://github.com/oampo/Audiolet/

WebPD.js
https://github.com/sebpiq/WebPd